# Why do I get zip error while creating a file copy program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a program for copying files to directories but I'm getting an error:

> Unable to find threadStateIndex for the current thread. curPyThread:
>   0x7f8090c03050
>
> zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qr
>   Users/ketiaslanishvili/Desktop/20190811154406.zip . -i
>   Users/ketiaslanishvili/Desktop/Video/1.mp4)

My code :

```
import os
import time


source = ['"Users/ketiaslanishvili/Desktop/Video"' ]

target_dir = 'Users/ketiaslanishvili/Desktop'
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')+'.zip'
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}" .format(target, '' .join(source))


if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Completed', target)
else:
    print('Unsucsesful:((((((')
```

Comment: I'd start by trying the zip command directly in the shell. Your problem doesn't actually seem to be a python problem.

Comment: Note that the error message is from zip, not Python

Comment: Suggestion: check into `psutil` library, it simplifies this task.

Comment: @JaredSmith it's a Python problem because it's Python that generates the incorrect command line.